# Vue: Works differently for different devices

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keyup

I have used a filter function `searchTags()` inside a Vue component for the `keyup` event, which suggest the matching words after user type 3 letters.
I use Laravel for the backend.

```
<input @keyup="searchTags()" 
       id="search_tags"
       placeholder="Search tag.."
       type="text" 
       v-model="search_term.tags">
```

When I check it with a Huawei Nova 3i, it works just fine. But when I check it with Samsung A30s it doesn't. I tried connecting Samsung A30s in debug mode, and the request is not firing and not showing any error in console.

What can be the solution for this?

Comment: As far as I know keyup has issues. `v-on:input` might help.

Comment: Or use a watcher for search term tags where you fire off the search function? Even better if you couple it with a debouncer.